# Change the all images webp file extension on Safari browser when my website load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Need help I am trying to change the all images webp extension into "png" when my website load on safari browser.

```
Webp image path


    <img class="img-fluid" src="image/img-1.webp" alt="">
    <img class="img-fluid" src="image/img-2.webp" alt="">
    <img class="img-fluid" src="image/img-3.webp" alt="">
```

I want to change into png extension

```
    <img class="img-fluid" src="image/img-1.png" alt="">
    <img class="img-fluid" src="image/img-2.png" alt="">
    <img class="img-fluid" src="image/img-3.png" alt="">



$(document).ready(function () {

   if($.browser.safari){
    $("body").each(function(){
        var imageExtension = $("img").attr('src').split('.').pop();  
        for(var i = 0; i < $("img").length; i++)
    {
        extensionChange = imageExtension.replace(imageExtension,'.png' );
        console.log(extensionChange);
    }
    $("img").attr('src').split('.').pop();
    });
    }
});
```

Comment: Where is `var extensionChange`? Do you have a several `body`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to loop the `images` in `body`. You are almost there little bit modified your code.

```
if($.browser.safari){
    $("body img").each(function(){
    var imageExtension = $(this).attr('src').split('.').pop();  

    for(var i = 0; i < $(this).length; i++)
    {
        extensionChange = imageExtension.replace(imageExtension,'png' );
        console.log(extensionChange);
    }

    src = $(this).attr('src');
    src = src.replace(imageExtension,extensionChange);

    $(this).attr('src', src);
});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do it without js, use tag `<picture>`, read about it here: [how to use picture tag](https://medium.com/front-end-weekly/html-picture-tag-in-practice-png-and-webp-formats-5a3fc51b5998)